# In terms of time complexity/performance, are the following two equivalent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I assume that the way `contains()` work in JS is that it loops through all the children and children of children and checks each one if it is a match with the parameter element. Assuming that is the case, I would think the follow two statements are equivalent as they would require equally many "checks" regardless (except for the check on the parent of course). Am I correct? My intuition tells me I am not and that the second approach be more intensive?

Check parent and its children:

```
parentElement.contains(someChild);
```

Check parents children only:

```
Array.from(parentElement.children).some(child => child.contains(e.target));
```

Comment: the two approaches you mentioned are not entirely equivalent, and the performance can differ based on the structure of the `DOM`.  First scenario is a direct check and is more efficient while second approach is less efficient in scenarios where there are too many children

Comment: @ChrisG Interesting, how come? Wouldn't an equal amount of elements need to be checked either way?

Comment: the 1st approach It's a direct check, and if `someChild` is deeply nested within `parentElement`, the check is more efficient.  If the DOM has a small structure, performance difference between the two, will not be significant.

Comment: @ChrisG But why is the check more efficient? What do you mean by direct check?

Comment: that's because the `contains` method directly checks whether a given element is a descendant of another element, and it does so without iterating over all the children of the parent element explicitly.

Comment: In the first example you call a highly optimized function. In the second example, you first create an array and copy all the children to it. You have already spent time that the first example don't use. Then you are calling the function `some` that call your supplied function that calls contain. A lot of extra work. That is why the second example is slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging for a while a finally figured out why the second approach is slower.

My understanding was that contains starts from the parent element and recursively iterates over all its children to check for a match. This is however not correct.

Instead contains starts from the input element and traverses up the DOM tree (Not down it like I originally thought). This means that in the first approach, we need to make that trip only once, whereas in the second approach we need to make that trip `n` times where `n` is the number of childs of the parent element.